# In AS2, how to concatinate variable names?

Tags: flash, loops, actionscript-2

I'm trying to loop through a set of textFields that I created in the Flash IDE, and named them through the property panel with name called "dot_text1, dot_text2, etc...). These textfield elements are nested in another movieclip called "bouquet".

My issue is that I'm trying to loop through all of them and store them into an Array for later use, but I keep getting undefined when I trace it out. I'm writing the script in the root of the file.

```
for (var i=0; i <11; i++) {
    trace(["bouquet.dot_text" + i]); 
}
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong :(. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking to store all the controls in an array, this should do it:

```
var inputs = new Array();
for (var i=0; i <11; i++) {
    inputs.push(bouquet["dot_text" + i]);
}
```

In your example, you're saying:

```
trace(["bouquet.dot_text" + i])
```

Which is actually saying

"print out the trace for a one-element array containing the text "bouquet.dot_text" + i

when what you want to say is

"print out the trace for the member named "dot_text" + 1 in the object named bouquet.

So your example probably *should* read something like this:

```
for (var i=0; i <11; i++) {
    trace(bouquet["dot_text" + i]); 
}
```

[edit]

The OP expressed confusion over the use of "brackets for concatenating variable names". What's actually going on here is a pretty cool feature of the JavaScript family of languages: *objects are also associative arrays*, so when you declare an object like this:

```
var obj = {member: "value"};
// now, obj.member == "value"
```

you can also access its member variables as if it were an associative array:

```
obj["member"]
```

Now, since you can use a string representing the name of the member as a key to the array, obviously you can also concatenate to that string, so:

```
var obj = {member1: "value1", member2: "value2"};
var value1 = obj["member" + 1];
var value2 = obj["member" + 2];
```

and this, of course, is something you can do with a loop variable or what have you.

What's wrong in OP's original example is that they're not accessing an array, they're *creating* one:

```
// this accesses the "member" key in the assoc. array "obj"
var value = obj["member"];
// this creates a new 1-element array containing the string "member"
var array = ["member"];
```

So the brackets don't really have anything to do with concatenating variable names; in one context they denote an array literal, in another they denote array access. Hope this clarifies things a bit? :-)

Comment: Thanks Rytmis for the quick reply. I was confused with the whole brackets for concatenating variable names, and the fact there isn't a "period" needed after the bouquet. Interesting. So I take it that the MC is just treated like an array?

Comment: Hold on a sec, I'm going to amend my actual answer for this one. :-)

Comment: Wow, that really helped to clear things up for me. Thanks Rytmis!